# Placement of defer after error check

Tags: go

In Go, one often sees the following idiom:

```
func CopyFile(dstName, srcName string) (written int64, err error) {
    src, err := os.Open(srcName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer src.Close()

    dst, err := os.Create(dstName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    return io.Copy(dst, src)
}
```

Is there any reason why the `defer` statement comes after the error check? My guess is that this is done in order to avoid dereferencing `nil` values in case `err` was not `nil`.

Comment: If opening a file fails, there is nothing to close

Answer (score 1):

If the file `Open` or `Create` fails then you don't have a valid `*File` to close. The problem wouldn't be a `nil` value for `*File` as `Close`() will check for `nil` and simply return immediately in that case - the problem might be if the `*File` value is non-nil but invalid. Since documentation for  `os.Open()` doesn't explicitly state that a failed call to `Open()` returns a nil value for `*File` you can't rely that all underlying implementations of it do in fact return a nil value or will always return a nil value..